# How can I pass a variable from one page(view) to another on GET?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to pass on GET a variable from one page to another.

On the next page, in the view/template I check the variable, and if exist I make some adjustments how the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it as context.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        my_variable = request.GET.get('my_variable')
        return render(request, 'template.html', context={'my_variable': my_variable})
```